# counting principles: how many possible passwords can be made

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many passwords can be made if a password should be composed of two English letters 
followed by four decimal digits or two decimal digits followed by four English letters? Assume that 
passwords are not case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

The way I always think about these problems is that each time you add a letter or digit you multiplicatively increase the number of possible arrangements. Binary is a simple and intuitive case where each time you add a digit you double the amount of possible values.

With regards to your question if you had a single letter you would have 26 different possible passwords. Each time you add a letter or digit you would multiply the number of possible passwords by 10 for decimal digits and 26 for letters. This should apply no matter how the digits or letters are ordered.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you can choose the first letter in 26 ways, the second letter in 26 ways and each of the digits in 10 ways, which gives you $26^2\cdot 10^4$ possible passwords.

The same reasoning can be applied to the second case